# Query to select next few rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, fts4

I'm working on a search tool, the words (to be searched) are in object array
first I search the database(about 450k rows) using FTS4 and sqlite. This works fast, the SQL I'm using  is:

```
String s =  "select * from  fts_sggs where word_text MATCH ? ";
```

but then, I need some extra words which are a part of the same table.
The FTS4 doesn't seem to work here. The SQL is:

```
String s ="select * from fts_sggs where word_number BETWEEN " + wordnumlo + " AND " + wordnumhi + " and page_number =" + pgnum;
```

I'm a newbie to SQL Programming, I need a single query that could perform both tasks fast. this is being done in java which is terribly slow.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would a UNION be an idea for you, since you return same structure ? `https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-union/` 
If second query depends on first query  have a look at "recursive" query for SQLite.

Comment: UNION no idea ! recursive ill try

Comment: `select * from fts_sgss where word_text MATCH ?  UNION select * from fts_sgss where...`  is one example. Here, the two queries are separate and last does not depend on results from first one.

Comment: UNION worked but only for first item rest 9326 were all only the first query output

Comment: Could you edit your post and make a simplified example of some data example ?